# How to sort array in descending order

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have a method that prints out my cards below. I want to create a method that will print out the cards in descending order. I would have to create a new method. I've tried a few things but here I am.

```
    def print_cards    
      cards.all.each.with_index(1) do |card, index|
        puts "#{index}. #{card.name}"
      end 
    end
```

Comment: Can you show what `cards` looks like and a concrete example of the actual and expected results? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the sort_by method of Ruby's [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) module.

The basic idea is you provide a block that maps each value in the enumeration into a numerical value that can be used to sort the collection.

For example if you have a collection of Strings and you want to sort them by length you can use something like this where each item in the collection is mapped to its size/length.  The first example sorts the array in ascending order while the second sorts in descending order.

```
my_array = ["a", "aa", "aaaa", "aaa"]

puts my_array.sort_by { |item| item.size }
puts my_array.sort_by { |item| -item.size }
```

Comment: Damn, that's clean as hell. I've always done the full |a, b| a <=> b, and swapping to b <=> a for a reverse sort. But that way you did it is actually so much cleaner